# Restrict the number of times a button can be tapped

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

Is it possible to restrict number of times a button can be hit in a certain time frame? I have an activity indicator and refresh button on a web view in my app. I have the refresh button working, but if you hit it more than once, multiple activity indicators appear on top of each other.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to restrict number of times a button can be hit in a certain time frame?

It's not possible to restrict the number of times the user tries to tap the button (unless you hide the button), but it's certainly possible to respond to the button, or even whether the button will respond to the user. For example, your app could disable the button while it's performing an update. That would give the user a visual cue that the button isn't available, and the activity indicator will tell them that the app is doing something.

Answer (score 2):

i just want to make a suggestion for a different approach.
It sounds like you are adding an activity indicator to the view every time you hit the button. if this is the case you could first create a property for the indicator, set the activity indicator in the view in viewDidAppear method and just start the it when you hit the button. than you can check if the indicator is already animating and either start it again or don't.